# Itemselector items use different datatemplates but should share a view model

Tags: c#, wpf

Right now I'm using a custom items control with three different data templates, three view models, and an itemtemplate selector.

Everything is working, but I am looking on improving this code. Here are the three data templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RefreshDevicesDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5,0">
        <myApp:myAppButton Name="RefreshButton" Command="{Binding Command}" ToolTip="Refresh Devices" Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}">
            <Rectangle x:Name="RefreshRectangle" Width="20" Height="20" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Fill="{Binding IconBrush}" Opacity="1" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
        </myApp:myAppButton>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWaiting}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" TargetName="RefreshRectangle" />
        </DataTrigger>                
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeviceDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5,0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="IconRectangle" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding IconBrush}" Opacity="0.5" ToolTip="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" TargetName="IconRectangle" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5,0">
        <myApp:myAppButton Style="{DynamicResource ChromelessButtonStyle}" Foreground="White" Content="{Binding CommandName, Converter={StaticResource LowerCaseConverter}}"
               Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
               FontFamily="Marlett"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my template selector:

```
<models:WindowCommandItemTemplateSelector x:Key="WindowCommandTemplateSelector" DeviceTemplate="{StaticResource DeviceDataTemplate}" CommandTemplate="{StaticResource CommandDataTemplate}" RefreshCommandTemplate="{StaticResource RefreshDevicesDataTemplate}"/>
```

---

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {

        DataTemplate resultTemplate = null;

        if (item is DeviceViewModel)
        {
            resultTemplate = DeviceTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is WindowCommandViewModel) // I need two view models because I can't know which template to use with just one class.
        {
            resultTemplate = CommandTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is RefreshCommandViewModel) // here too
        {
            resultTemplate = RefreshCommandTemplate;
        }

        return resultTemplate;
}
```

The template selector just selects the template based on the view model that's passed in.

Finally I specify my itemscontrol:

```
<myApp:myAppWindow.WindowCommands>
    <myApp:WindowCommands ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource WindowCommandTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding WindowCommands}" />
</myApp:myAppWindow.WindowCommands>
```

Here's the deal: I have a different view model for each of these data templates, but really, the `RefreshButton` and the `CommandDataTemplate` are just buttons with different templates. I have some different bindings, such as `IsWaiting`, but those can just be dealt with in the parent view model.

Does there need to be a 1-1 correspondence between view models and datatemplates if I want to keep adding custom templates to this itemscontrol?

Maybe I could create some static property and check that? Is there a more WPF-y way to do this? I'm very new to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is confusing, but I think you are trying to avoid creating multiple viewmodel types. That's easy with a `DataTemplateSelector` as you can execute whatever logic within it that you want. You might inspect the value of `MySharedViewModel.Command` and return a template depending on precisely which command it is, for example.

> Does there need to be a 1-1 correspondence between view models and datatemplates if I want to keep adding custom templates to this itemscontrol?

No, because bindings look up properties by name at runtime. Your binding to `Command` will match both `RefreshCommandTemplate.Command` and `DeviceViewModel.Command`.

The only time you would need a 1:1 mapping is if you were to use the [`DataTemplate.DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which is a XAML shortcut which avoids the need to create a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Right, I don't know how I missed that. My view model has a command name which I can simply check in the data template selector... thanks.